# Python parallel data processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing

We have a dataset which has approx 1.5MM rows. I would like to process that in parallel. The main function of that code is to lookup master information and enrich the 1.5MM rows. The master is a two column dataset with roughly 25000 rows. However i am unable to make the multi-process work and test its scalability properly. Can some one please help.  The cut-down version of the code is as follows

```
import pandas
from multiprocessing import Pool

def work(data):
    mylist =[]
    #Business Logic
    return mylist.append(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_df = pandas.read_csv('D:\\retail\\customer_sales_parallel.csv',header='infer')
    print('Source Data :', data_df)
    agents = 2
    chunksize = 2
    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
            result = pool.map(func=work, iterable= data_df, chunksize=20)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
    print('Result :', result)
```

Method `work` will have the business logic and i would like to pass partitioned data_df into `work` to enable parallel processing. The sample data is as follows

```
CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,SALE_QTY
641996,115089,2
1078894,78144,1
1078894,121664,1
1078894,26467,1
457347,59359,2
1006860,36329,2
1006860,65237,2
1006860,121189,2
825486,78151,2
825486,78151,2
123445,115089,4
```

Ideally i would like to process 6 rows in each partition.

Please help.

Thanks and Regards

Bala

Comment: Why are you passing a dataframe to multiprocessing that involves appending to lists? You haven't given enough info to answer this properly, but you'll probably either `join` or `merge` the data sources. It'll be faster than multiprocessing too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `work` is returning the output of `mylist.append(data)`, which is `None`. I assume (and if not, I suggest) you want to return a processed Dataframe.

To distribute the load, you could use `numpy.array_split` to split the large Dataframe into a list of 6-row Dataframes, which are then processed by `work`.

```
import pandas
import math
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def work(data):
    #Business Logic
    return data # Return it as a Dataframe

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_df = pandas.read_csv('D:\\retail\\customer_sales_parallel.csv',header='infer')
    print('Source Data :', data_df)
    agents = 2
    rows_per_workload = 6
    num_loads = math.ceil(data_df.shape[0]/float(rows_per_workload))
    split_df = np.array_split(data_df, num_loads) # A list of Dataframes
    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
        result = pool.map(func=work, iterable=split_df)
        result = pandas.concat(result) # Stitch them back together    
        pool.close()
        pool.join()pool = Pool(processes=agents)
    print('Result :', result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I certainly would want to return a data frame. Will try the code that you have listed here with my business logic. Thanks once again

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if you're happy with it :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this pretty much solved my problem. Just one quick follow up question please, the method `work` takes two parameters as in `work(master,data)` how can i pack that please

Comment: This is a much more common question; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) for example. I'd take a look at `pool.starmap`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Let me take a look at that.

Comment: Still not able to get this going. I will 'ask' a new question on this please

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation is for you to use the **chunksize** parameter in read_csv ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)) and iterate over. This way you wont crash your ram trying to load everything plus if you want you can for example use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to speed up the process.

```
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('bigfile.csv', chunksize=500000)):
```

Im not sure if this answer your specific question but i hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt using Python threads will speed up the process due to the GIL. Multiprocess is the only "real" way to use parallelism in Python.

Comment: @marco Typekazt  
Thanks for your response. I would like to Multi-process and not multi-thread please

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan The you have this docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html wich i didnt know about but for what i read its really similar to threading (on the outside at least)